# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when trying to upload a spring cloud function inside a .zip in AWS Lambda

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to upload a small Spring cloud function app inside a .zip but the runtime can't find the handler method.

The app works just fine if I deploy a .jar directly. But I need to deploy as a .zip because I need to import the ssl certificate for the Database connection. But then the runtime can't find the handler method

```
Class not found: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker. Current classpath: file:/var/task/
```

here's the runtime settings:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGrfo.png)

It's important to point out that if I upload a .zip, it doesn't work regardless if the .zip cointains only the .jar or both the .jar and the .crt, as if lambda "fails to unzip properly"

Not so sure what to do, or is importing a ssl certificate to a lambda function just a bad idea altogether?

Comment: Are you zipping the jar file?  You need to deploy the files in the zip, not the jar.  And a jar *is a* zip file so it's unclear why you can't use a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `maven-shade-plugin`?

I don't know your full config, but you need to create "fat" jar with all the dependencies, for that you need to configure your `pom.xml` file in such way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
<!-- required dependencies, add those that you also need -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<!--Useful thing to manage some dependencies -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

<!-- There comes the magic:) -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This way all classes from all dependencies will be in that jar, but the package size will be huge, consider using lambda layers

If u need such thing for gradle, text me, I'm happy to help (: